# getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); goes out of the application.. instead of going to parent activ

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have splash screen, register/login and then menu once the authentication is successful. I wanted a back button for my menu options so I used getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); I also specified parent activity on the manifest file. However, when I press the button it just goes out of the app? It does not close it but goes out so when I re-open it I have to sign in all over again.. Any ideas why this is happening? I am really frustrated.

Comment: What error is displayed in the application؟

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are navigation from `LoginActivity` to `MenuActivity`. For this set `LoginActivity` as parent of `MenuActivity` in `manifest.xml`. I know you would have declared, but trick is who is parent of whom. Like:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity">
    </activity>
```

Above code means `MenuActivity` has to be created from `LoginActivity` and when back arrow on `MenuActivity` will be pressed then `LoginActivity` will be shown.

And set `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` inside `MenuActivity` to show back arrow.